# Extra HDD (Hdd Caddy) Slows down ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, ssd

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my SSD drive and everything went OK.
But I noticed that the system is too slow, and after some search i found that the problem is caused by my HDD which is connected to my computer
using a Hard Caddy.

After removing the Hard Caddy Ubuntu works very smoothly.

I am newbie with Linux, So I just let it install itself on my SSD 
without doing any partitioning.

---

**Edit:** I tried **hdparm** to get informations about my hdd:

- **sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb** and the output:

  ```
  /dev/sdb:  
  Timing cached reads:      12704 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6367.76MB/sec  
  Timing buffered disk reads: 314 MB in  3.01 seconds = 104.46MB/sec
  ```
- **sudo hdparm -v /dev/sdb** the output is:

  ```
  /dev/sdb:  
  multcount     =  0 (off)  
  IO_support    =  1 (32-bit) 
  readonly      =  0 (off)  
  readahead     = 256 (on)  
  geometry      = 121601/255/63, sectors = 1953525168, start = 0
  ```
- **sudo hdparm -i /dev/sdb**

  ```
  PIO modes:  pio0 pio3 pio4 
  DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
  UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
  AdvancedPM=yes: unknown setting WriteCache=enabled
  Drive conforms to: Unspecified:  ATA/ATAPI-1,2,3,4,5,6,7
  ```

---

BTW, [This is how Disks Utility shows my Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCX0i.png).
It seems likes there is still a partition which is considered 
as a filesystem system partition, I'll try to format this partition.

Comment: Likely not a problem with the caddie, which has no built-in electronics. Perhaps a problem with your HDD. What says `hdparm` about it?

Comment: I just edited my question with the results @xenoid

Comment: A last one: `hdparm -i /dev/sdb`, and see which of `pio`/`dma`/`udma` it is using (the one with the asterisk). It should normally be using the last `udma` mode. My own HDD says `multcount=16 (on)`. but I don't know what impact this has.